# How to get FROM and TO address updated dynamically in the "Create Email as quick action with LWC"?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am trying to implement "Create an Email as a Quick Action" using below:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_email

https://www.salesforcebolt.com/2023/02/create-email-as-quick-action-in-LWC.html

As per my scenario, I have to get the FROM and TO address from Org Wide Email Address and User Email address respectively. Is there is any possibility of achieving it using the functionality? If yes, could someone please help in this.

Thanks for all the great help.

Regards,
Anudeep Revuru

I tried using "Toaddress" field from EmailMessage object but still we are not able to update the To and From Addresses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can query Orgwideaddress from apex and call apex from LWC and add the response in defaultfieldvalues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).